# how to allow django rest api to response requests made from different hosts?

Tags: angularjs, cors, django-rest-framework

i developed a web api using djangorestframework but when i am consuming api using angularJS, browser shows error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8000/webapi/orders. Response > to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-
>   Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin > 'http://127.0.0.1:37749' is therefore not allowed access.

- angularJS app is hosted on 127.0.0.1:37749/ and
- django api is hosted on 127.0.0.1:8000/

how to configure settings.py to solve this problem?
please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are having an issue with Cross Origin Resource Sharing.

See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/#cors for solution. In particular django-cors-headers is what you'll want to fix that issue.

Comment: hi thanks for answer. I followed steps in link you provided, but now browser shows  `Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin 
 ? is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers 
in preflight response`.    can you please explain?

Comment: no idea. Following the django-cors-headers guide I managed to get it working as well as the workshop attendees.